# Centroid problem with side ratios

Tags: geometry

Note: The question has two "parts," however, treat the two "parts" like two separate questions.

a) Let $G$ denote the centroid of triangle $ABC$. Let $M$ and $N$ be points on sides $AB$ and $AC$, respectively, so that $M$, $G$, and $N$ are collinear, and $ AM/MB = 5/2 $. Find $AN/NC$.

b) In triangle $ABC$, $AD$ and $BE$ are medians. We also have that $AD$ and $BE$ are perpendicular. If $AC=22$ and $BC=31$, then find $AB$.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is $AM/MB$ really $\frac{5}{2}$? If so, what makes you think $AN/NC$ is determined?

Comment: -1 It is time this was corrected. In general you will not have $MN$ parallel to $BC$ in part a).

Comment: @almagest It's "collinear" not "parallel"

Comment: @Aditya. Just so. Do you think $AN/NC$ is determined? If so, why?

Comment: @almagest its undetermined but where did you get that parallel thing?

Comment: @almagest I don't if you have some understanding problem so that I have to repeat 1000 times "its undetermined", this's the last one!

Answer (score 3):

Here are figures for helping.
$$(a)\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad (b)$$
[image]

---

a) for $$A\equiv(3.32,4.42),B\equiv(-2,-0.13),C\equiv(10.08,0.64),M\equiv(-0.47,1.16)$$
I get $AN=4.83,NC=2.92,AN/NC=1.65$
Only changing poition of C to $(6.54,-3.31)$ gives $AN=5.23,NC=3.15,AN/NC=1.66$
Maybe something's wrong.

---

b) Given:
$$AC=22,BC=31$$
Since D and E are midpoints:
$$\implies BD=31/2,AE=11$$
Now a pretty famous result for centroid is that:
$$\frac{AG}{GD}=\frac{BG}{GE}=\frac{CG}{GF}=\frac21$$
Now let $AD=3x,BE=3y$
So by pythagoreas theorem:
$$\underbrace{(2x)^2}_{AG^2}+\underbrace{y^2}_{GE^2}=\underbrace{121}_{AE^2}\\
\underbrace{(2y)^2}_{BG^2}+\underbrace{x^2}_{GD^2}=\underbrace{961/4}_{BD^2}$$
Solving we get:
$$x^2=\frac{65}4,y^2=56$$
Again:
$$\underbrace{(2x)^2}_{AG^2}+\underbrace{(2y)^2}_{BG^2}=AB^2$$
So $AB=17$.

---

Comment: @math-sd see the edit.

Comment: Question says $AM/MB=5/2$, so $AN/NC$ is not determined!

Comment: @almagest wait I'm typing

Comment: but why the downvote?

Comment: Because the answer seems to be wrong. What have the midpoints got to do with it? $MN$ is not parallel to $BC$ in general.

Comment: does your computer show you some other answer, or are you making things up beacuse I haven't wrote $M$ or $N$ a single time in my post, it's part b

Comment: Well, you have yourself to blame for putting up two figures! If you could make an edit (any edit), I will remove the downvote.

Comment: @almagest i added it, now you can upvote

Comment: +1 I am sorry. Because no one had commented on the fact that the first half was a nonsense, I assumed that this answer was wrong too! I will try to be more careful!